# Image aligned to left

Tags: html, css

Please [check link](https://codepen.io/soorajbala/pen/JLbOgq?editors=1100) for more details on my code. I need to have the placeholder image aligned to left of the screen i.e. to the bank white space as illustrated by the shared code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main{ 
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
aside { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
article {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}

figure {
  padding-top : 50%;
  position:relative;
  img {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
     <figure>
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">         </figure>
  </article>
  <aside>

  </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/soorajbala/pen/JLbOgq?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
justify-content: flex-end;
```

from `.main` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In .main css you can remove justify-content or set it with flex-start, If you want to take red section in right and the image in left you can set justify-content space-between.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main{ 
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
aside { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
article {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}

figure {
  padding-top : 50%;
  position:relative;
  img {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
img{
  width:100%
    
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
  <article>
     <figure>
             
    </figure>
  </article>
  <aside>

  </aside>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here. When you set a `max-width`, when the size is more than 500px + 300px of the sidebar, you get the white space.

```
article {
  width: 100%;
  /*Issue is here.*/
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

To use the same code, you need to adjust the code to this. I will comment out the unnecessary part so you can delete them as you follow the code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main{ 
  /*width: 100%;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
aside { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
article {
  /*
  This is fine but use the flexbox syntax flex: 1 or flex-basis: 100% to get the remaining space from aside.
  width: 100%;*
  /
  /*Issue is here.
  max-width: 500px;
  */
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}

figure {
  /*
  Not needed.
  padding-top : 50%;
  position:relative;
  */
  img {
    /*
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
    */
    /*To make the image responsive and fit figure tag*/
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article>
     <figure>
       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">         </figure>
  </article>
  <aside>

  </aside>
</main>
```

Or else restructure your markup to have the `figure + image` out of the `article` into `main`